# How to send messages scraped from telegram channels using Telethon bot?

Tags: python, telethon

When iterated messages from a telegram channel is being sent using telethon bot, it raises `telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist.MediaEmptyError` error.

I am trying to scrap messages from a certain telegram channel using a **USER** client and then posting it using a bot client, but upto the point of scraping the messages, the code works but it raises an error when the bot tries to send the message to the user.
The bot works in such a way:

- User sends the bot the channel link
- the bot scrapes the channel and sends it to the user

**Code for the scraping and sending part**

```
async def scrape_channel(channel_name,chat_id):
    async for message in client2.iter_messages(entity=channel_name,limit=6, reverse=True,filter=types.InputMessagesFilterEmpty):
        if message.text or message.media and not message.sticker:
           await client.send_message(chat_id, messages=message)#chat_id here is the chat between the user and bot
```

If there are any inefficiencies in the code, please feel free to point out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `message` object, itered by `client2`, is accessible only by `client2`. If the `client` is a participant of `channel_name`, you can get the `message` using `await client.get_messages(channel_name, ids=[message.id])`, or, use `await client.send_message(chat_id, message.text, file=message.media, ..)` (the remaining params can be [found in the docs](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/modules/client.html#telethon.client.messages.MessageMethods.send_message)).

Hope it helps you out!

Comment: Hey thank you buddy for the help. So the solution to the problem would be like to get the messages using the user client, then get the messages again using the bot(using the ids of the iterated messages), then send the messages via the bot.

Comment: Yep, exactly...